# DataGrab: How to use relative URL? Or edit URL?

Tags: datagrab

I would like to configure DataGrab to use a relative path for its CSV importing. Is this possible? The reason for this is that I need to duplicate this site and don't want to hard code the domain name in the URL.

Alternatively, but not ideal, is there a way to edit the URL path? Maybe I can just edit the URLs for each copy of the site.

Comment: I've never used DataGrab.  Any chance that rather than using a relative url you can use the global variable {site_url}?